# How to use ViewDeck of IOS in Android?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout

I am working on an app that is in android and ios. I found this lib to help with view layouts. https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck but I'm not as lucky yet in android. Does anyone have a couple of libraries that do something similar?

(facebook and Path type of hidden menus)

for others. I found this list of ios libraries like the viewdeck one here.

http://bitly.com/bundles/o_27ukkruo5l/1

Thanks

Comment: Sliding Menu https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: This is exactly what we were looking for.

Comment: @RajeevNB why don't you publish it as an answer.